# How to get the list of programs that have been downloaded in android

Tags: android

How can I get the list of applications that have been downloaded
I mean that the supermarket and programs or sites have been downloaded and installed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean all the apps available on device as installed/downloaded, comment me if that is not the case please.

Use package manager as follows:

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

//List of installed app  assigned to 'packages'
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

//iterate through all the installed packages
for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
    Log.d(TAG, "Source directory : " + packageInfo.sourceDir);
    Log.d(TAG, "Launch Activity :" + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName)); 
}
```

- getLaunchIntentForPackage would return an intent which you could use later
- reference: http://qtcstation.com/2011/02/how-to-launch-another-app-from-your-app/